# Why copy-paste into MongoDB shell works, but read the same code from *.js file don't?

Tags: windows, mongodb, cmd

I got a list of commands to paste into mongodb shell. Usually I open cmd as Administrator, change directory to MongoDB bin folder, start mongo.exe and simply do copy-paste. My question how to write a correct file that will open mongo shell and send a list of commands directly? Tried saving the code example as test.js, but 'mongo.exe test.js' always returns Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier'. Still at the same time copy-paste runs without single error.

Here is a full code example:

```
    use admin
db.dropUser("root");
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
db.createUser(
{
user: "root",
pwd: "pswd",
customData: { description: "default admin user" },
roles: [
"readWriteAnyDatabase",
"userAdminAnyDatabase",
"dbAdminAnyDatabase",
"clusterAdmin"
]
}
);
use usersdb;
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
use maindb;
db.dropUser("somereader");
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
db.dropUser("someuser");
db.dropUser("someadmin");
db.createUser(
{
user: "somereader",
pwd: "somereader",
customData: { description: "maindb read-only user" },
roles: [
"read"
]
}
);
db.createUser(
{
user: "someuser",
pwd: "30d1ef22ff41d9b031b6e1d80a3cbd695ea78835f821093f6f836bbe6107aa5b",
customData: { description: "maindb app user" },
roles: [
"readWrite",
{role: "read", db: "someusers"},
{role: "read", db: "admin"},
{role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin"}
]
}
);
db.createUser(
{
user: "someadmin",
pwd: "eac55b089924b85e17a44070ed7cb0ebef74263786fccaf005f5955eafaae934",
customData: { description: "maindb admin user" },
roles: [
"readWrite",
"dbAdmin",
{role: "readWrite", db: "someusers"},
{role: "dbAdmin", db: "someusers"},
{role: "read", db: "admin"},
{role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin"}
]
}
);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-arg-file-js

Comment: I always get 'Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier' if open from js-file or as --eval in command line. But direct copy-paste works. Tell me please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "Is it possible" is not a question that suits the rules of this site. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! And provide a [mcve] of your code!

Comment: Just create a javascript file to batch your operations, run the script on command with mongo - `mongo javascript-file.js` and you can also create a `bash` script with this mongo command and execute directly.

Comment: @RaKa just try on your own with code example. Would not work.

Comment: Dear Slavik, stackoverflow doesn't work this way. Do yourself a favour - read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Running js scripts in mongo client definitely work when done properly. If you have errors, most likely you did something wrong. You can ask for help here providing minimal and reproducible example, including the command you are actually using and full error message - which line it complains about? Of the top of my head, `use` statements are not going to work in the script and should be like `var db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');`

Answer (score 1):

First, create a JavaScript file to batch your operations:

```
test.js
//#####################################
var count = db.foo.find().count()
print("Total count:"+count)
```

Now, on terminal:

```
mongo <db-name> test.js

Output:
MongoDB shell version v3.4.15
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/foo
MongoDB server version: 3.4.15
Total count: 68
```

Note, that script file won't support `use <database>`, therefore you must provide name on `mongo` command. Refer to official doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/